# Blocks unwanted dependencies in C# project or solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, nuget

I aim to exclude specific references to a library or any transitive dependencies during the solution build, with the desired outcome being a build error.

This code is designed to function with explicit dependencies.

```xml
<!-- directory.build.target -->
<Project>
    <Target Name="RemoveDeps" AfterTargets="ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild">
        <Error Code="420" Text="Blocked package dependency detected: %(PackageReference.Identity):%(PackageReference.Version)" 
            Condition="'%(PackageReference.Identity)' == 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions' and '%(PackageReference.Version)' == '2.2.0'" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

If I run the build it succesfully prompt that I cannot use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions:2.2.0`.

The current process fails when attempting to check for transitive dependencies. To address this, I need to switch from using `%(PackageReference)` to `%(PackageDependencies)`. However, the latter does not include any `Version` metadata; its value is consistently empty.

```xml
<!-- directory.build.target -->
<Project>
    <Target Name="RemoveDeps" AfterTargets="ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild">
        <Error Code="420" Text="Blocked package dependency detected: %(PackageDependencies.Identity):%(PackageDependencies.Version)" 
            Condition="'%(PackageDependencies.Identity)' == 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions' and '%(PackageDependencies.Version)' == '2.2.0'" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Is this a legacy style or SDK style project? I assume SDK style but I'm asking to confirm. What is the target framework?

Comment: `Version` is metadata for the `PackageReference` item collection but it is not a standard or [well-known item metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2022) value. If you run the `-preprocess` switch you will get output that is your project with all imports. You might use that to analyze if there is a point in the build logic where the versions of transitive dependencies are available.